# typeError: Failed to fetch / REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost

Estoy realizando un trabajo en React JS en el cual lo levanto con `npm start` y se abre en `localhost:3000` en la página de inicio del proyecto. Cuando cargo mis datos para ingresar, demora en cargar y tira este error:

> typeError: Failed to fetch

No realicé ningún cambio extraño más que solo estilos en mis componentes y me levantaba lo más bien pero ahora no.

Lo instale en una Mac también (la mía es Dell con Ubuntu) y no hubo ningún problema ese primer dia, al segundo dia, el mismo error.

¿Qué es lo que está pasando o cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Va imagen de muestra:

Mirando en network la Request URL es la de mi api: https://api.workers.com.ar/v1/users/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Revisa esto por favor: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: @fredyfx muchas gracias por la edicion. La pregunta la realizo luego de hacer averiguaciones y navegar por internet investigando. Pero como no soy experto en react, no tengo suficiente experiencia para terminar de resolver este problema. Ojala puedan ayudarme

Comment: Claro que podemos ayudarte, edita la pregunta, agrega el código que tienes, a tal punto que podamos reproducir el mismo caso que tienes, hay cientos de usuarios que ponen pedacitos de código que vagamente se puede inferir. Para una buena respuesta, crea una buena pregunta, en este caso, edita, agregando código, notarás la diferencia :D

Comment: `Failed to fetch` puede ocurrir por cien razones distintas. Si no agregas más contexto, no hay forma de adivinar. Saludos

Comment: Ahi estot agregando datos @AlterLagos a ver si suman y es mas facil de apuntar a la solucion.

Comment: Y esa URL, ¿de dónde la sacaste?

Comment: Es la de la plataforma, ya estaba subida y funcionando desde antes. Solamente ahora probando en local en un principio no tuve problemas para ver y utilizar la plataforma, y desde hoy recien me tira este error.

Comment: Probe tambien con el Repositorio viejo, antes de que se cambien los estilos, y tambien tira el mismo error @fredyfx

Comment: Me late que el problema es otro, si dices que funcionaba, quizás alguien haya cambiado la forma de la API, esa URL es interna, no tengo acceso a ella desde internet.

Comment: Acabo de hacer un fetch a esa URL y no funciona (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch). De hecho la página está caída también.

Comment: Asi es @Kiko_L obtuve user y pass de AWS donde tienen alojado todo, y no renovaron el pago asi que se cayo todo por eso no funciona el request a esa api.